# How to avoid T-SQL to treat NaT datetime as zero datetime, instead treat them as null?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, t-sql, ssms-2017

I have a pandas dataframe which includes a column named "date" and its type is datetime64[ns].
some date values are missing and therefore are filled in with value NaT which is np.datetime64('NaT').
when I import it to T-SQL database using fts.fast_to_sql() method from fast_to_sql library, I see in SSMS that the NaT values are stored with zero datetime as "0001-01-01 00:00:00.0000000".
I want T-SQL to treat those missing dates as NULL, because in my table I have allowed Nulls and when I change the zero times to NULL, SSMS changes the record, So I assume that it is possible.

```
            dataframe=pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.Series(["2022-01-01 00:00:00",np.datetime64('NaT'),],
                                    dtype='datetime64[ns]')}) 

            driver='ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server'
            server = 'desktop-curtnl0\sqlexpress'
            Trusted_Connection='yes'
            username = ''
            password = ''
            creds = dict(driver=driver,
                                server=server,
                                database_name=database_name,
                                Trusted_Connection=Trusted_Connection,
                                username=username,
                                password=password)
            connection='driver={%s};server=%s;database=%s;Trusted_Connection=%s;uid=%s;pwd=%s' %\
                            ( creds['driver'], creds['server'], creds['database_name'],
                            creds['Trusted_Connection'], creds['username'] , creds['password']  )
                    
            conn = pyodbc.connect(connection)
            create_statement = fts.fast_to_sql(df=dataframe,
                                                            name="test",
                                                            conn=conn,
                                                            if_exists="replace",
                                                            temp=False)
            conn.commit()
            conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. It will change the NaT to None. When you upload it to SQL, it will be interpreted as null.

```
df = df.replace({np.nan: None})
```